# How to repeat the same video continuously from url video link?

Tags: java, android

hi have an android application build in android studio, this app runs a video with video view from an external link,

the video works, now my question is how do I make this same video being streamed from a url link to repeat continuously?

here is my java code.

public class MainActivity extends Activity

```
VideoView videoView;

MediaController controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoView=findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    controller=new MediaController(this);

    videoView.setMediaController(controller);


    videoView.setVideoPath("http://strecker.co.za/ad_system/videos/video1.mp4");

    videoView.start();  } }
```

here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `setOnCompletionListener and after complete video start again video.

```
VideoView videoView;

MediaController controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoView=findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    controller=new MediaController(this);

    videoView.setMediaController(controller);


    videoView.setVideoPath("http://strecker.co.za/ad_system/videos/video1.mp4");

    videoView.start();  

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.start();
       }
    });

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no android expert, but I would suggest putting a loop around `videoView.start()`.

If `VideoView` has a method to determine if the video has finished or is currently running, that could be the condition for the `start()` method to be called again. Otherwise you could look into whether calling `start()` whilst the video is already playing has an effect? Is an exception thrown, etc? If not you could call it once every second to replay the video once it has finished.

If all else fails you could call `start()` and then `Thread.sleep()` for the duration of the video. If `VideoView` has a method to return the length of the video you could use that, else hardcode the value.

Comment: The other answers posted since are much more concise and complete :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```